# Additional resource generator with sbt native packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a submodule, that is compiled by invoking external command. I would like to include generated file into jar. So I wrote a task:
```

```
myTask := {
  import sys.process.stringSeqToProcess
  Seq("my", "command") !
}
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "dist"
cleanFiles <+= baseDirectory { base => base / "dist" }

Keys.`package` <<= (Keys.`package` in Compile) dependsOn npmBuildTask.toTask
```

and when I invoke `mySubmodule/package` task it works well. But when I invoke `stage` task from `sbt-native-packager` my task is ignored(is not executed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options to solve this issue. I assume you want to add the `dist` folder to your resulting application jar.

Your configuration doesn't work because `stage` doesn't depend on `package`. This results `npmBuildTask` not being called.

### 1. Add dependency to stage

The easiest way to fix this is by simply adding the `npmBuildTask` as a dependency to `stage`

```
stage <<= stage dependsOn npmBuildTask.toTask
```

I wouldn't recommend this approach.

### 2. Resource generators

SBTs [Resoure Generators](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html) are exactly defined for this purpose. An inline version could look like this

```
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  streams.value.log.info("running npm generator")
  val base = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "dist"

  // A resource generator returns a Seq[File]. This is just an example
  List("index.js", "test.js").map { file =>
    IO.writeLines(base / file, List("var x = 1"))
    base / file
  }
}.taskValue
```

Or you could extract this in an `AutoPlugin` to separate the "what" and "how.

#### 3. AutoPlugin and resource generators

Create `project/NpmPlugin.scala` and add the following content

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin

object NpmPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  override val requires = JvmPlugin
  override val trigger = AllRequirements

  object autoImport {
    val npmBuildTask = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("npm-build-task", "Runs npm and builds the application")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    // define a custom target directory for npm
    target in npmBuildTask := target.value / "npm",
    // the actual build task
    npmBuildTask := {
      val npmSource = (target in npmBuildTask).value
      val npmTarget = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "dist"
      // run npm here, which generates the necessary values
      streams.value.log.info("running npm generator")
      // move generated sources to target folder
      IO.copyDirectory(npmSource, npmTarget)
      // recursively get all files in the npmTarget
      (npmTarget ***).get
    },
    resourceGenerators in Compile += npmBuildTask.taskValue
  )

}
```

The `build.sbt` will then look like this

```
name := "resource-gen-test"
version := "1.0"

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

Pretty clean :)

#### 4. Use mappings

Last but not least you *could* use `mappings`. They are the low level detail that drives a lot of the package-generation in sbt. The main idea of this solution is to

- Create a task that returns a mapping definition ( `Seq[(File, String)]` )
- Append this to the appropriate mappings

The advantage of this approach is that you are more flexible where you want to put your mappings.

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.Universal
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.autoImport.NativePackagerHelper._

object NpmMappingsPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  override val requires = JvmPlugin
  override val trigger = AllRequirements

  object autoImport {
    val npmBuildTask = TaskKey[Seq[(File, String)]]("npm-build-task", "Runs npm and builds the application")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    // define a custom target directory for npm
    target in npmBuildTask := target.value / "npm" / "dist",
    // the actual build task
    npmBuildTask := {
      val npmTarget = (target in npmBuildTask).value
      // run npm here, which generates the necessary values
      streams.value.log.info("running npm generator")   
      // recursively get all files in the npmTarget
      // contentOf(npmTarget) would skip the top-level-directory
      directory(npmTarget)
    },
    // add npm resources to the generated jar
    mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ++= npmBuildTask.value,

    // add npm resources to resulting package
    mappings in Universal ++= npmBuildTask.value
  )

}
```

As you can see in this approach we can easily add the resulting files to different mappings.

However I only recommend this approach if you need this kind of flexibility as it requires a bit more knowledge of native-packager.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I've found out the mapping-based solution on my own, but it was rather walking in a dark, now I understand what I'm doing :).